# Specifying the parameters for processing function qgis:joinattributestable with PyQGIS-3

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3

I would like to join a CSV and a vector layer, based on a field.

I know I can handle this with multiple lines like in first part of https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins_pyqgis.html .

However, in order to get things a bit shorter and clearer, I would like to use processing algorithm "qgis:joinattributestable".
Under Qgis2, `processing.runandload('qgis:joinattributestable', shp, csv, shpField, csvField, None)` would be the solution.

Now I'm under Qgis 3.8, I know I can use `processing.runandLoad('', parameters)`.
My question then is : **what are the keys of the values (shp, csv, shpField, csvField) that I have to feed `parameters` dictionnary with ?** And also where can I fin this information next time ?  (https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-field-value does not tell it if I'm right).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer...for those who would be interested : I had not thought about `processing.algorithmHelp("qgis:joinattributestable")`.

However, the question about an online database to find all the processing algorithms and their parameters is still up-to-date.